# Post-Build Event changes get ignored

Tags: tfs, build

I found out, that $ConfigurationName doesnt work on the Post-Build events in VS2010.
It has to be $(Configuration) as far as I've seen.

My problem now: The TFS-Buildserver seems to ignore this change:

If I check in the Change on the Solution and query a Build and open the Log, I still see "ConfigurationName" instead of Development or another Configuration.

Interesting enought, if I navigate trough the folders to the tfs output directory in the BuildsLogs folder, I see the correct value in the Log file, which is: Development

With this value a Batch-File gets called. I inserted a small test to check, which value gets passed:
copy "..\Configure_Development_Server.cmd" %2\Config\%4.txt   /Y

%4 should be the Configuration name.

Sadly, in the output I still get a ConfigurationName.txt file, not the wanted Development.txt.

Could you tell me, how I tell the Buildserver to take the new Postbuild event, and not the old one? At the moment, it seems like it's kindahow splitted between the old and the new one.

Thanks in advance and a good start in the new week!

Matthias

Comment: Are you setting the property via the TFS msbuild property to your desired configuration to build? e.g., /p:Configuration=Development Also, what are you trying to do after post build?

Comment: We're calling a CopyBuild.bat in the Project --> Properties --> Buildevents:

"$(SolutionDir)..\Global\CopyBuild.bat" " " "$(TargetDir)" " " $(Configuration) "$(OutDir)" REP WIN

But as said, it takes not the Configuration but the old value here.

Comment: Check what is in XML of your `*.*proj` file

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean: The problem is not $(Configuration), which is definitely right. The Problem ist the Tag, its that the TFS-Buildserver ignore the change in the Post-Event.